# Decide if the following series is converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Im trying to prove if the following series is converge -
I tried the ratio test but couldnt calculate the limit -

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(2n)^{n+2}}{(n+1)!}$$

Thanks for helping!

Comment: The Ratio Test will work, but there is an easier way.

Comment: Yeah.. much easier , Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$(n+1)!=(n+1)n(n-1)\cdots2\cdot1\lt(2n)(2n)(2n)\cdots(2n)(2n)=(2n)^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the Ratio Test

if convrge 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1 $$
so
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{(2n+2)^{n+3}}{(n+2)!}\frac{(n+1)!}{(2n)^{n+2}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{(2n+2)(2n+2)^{n+2}}{(n+2)(2n)^{n+2}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{n(2+2/n)}{n(1+2/n)}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+2}=2e$$